# Repeat UNNotifications every day and every half hour

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show local notifications to user between selected hours from user and repeat that notification for every half hour till the limit of the selected hour comes and also repeat this notification daily.
I have used this code

```
let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
     var triggerDate = DateComponents()
            triggerDate.hour = components.hour
            triggerDate.minute = components.minute
            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: true)
```

But this only repeats the notification daily at that specific time selected by user but I want to repeat this also at every half hour from that specific time.I have used UNNotifications.Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show local notifications for every half hour between selected hours then you have to set different notification for every hour with different notification identifier as:

```
var dateStart = "Pass Your Start Date for Notification."
let dateEnd = "Pass Your End Date for Notification."

//Check Start Date is less then End Date is not.        
while dateStart < dateEnd {

     dateStart = dateStart.addingTimeInterval(0.5 * 60 * 60) //Add half an hour to start time

    //Schedule notification With body and title.
    scheduleNotification(at: dateStart, body: "Show Me", titles: "Remainder")

}
```

Implement Notification by following function as:

```
//Schedule Notification with Daily bases.
func scheduleNotification(at date: Date, body: String, titles:String) {

    let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second], from: date)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = titles
    content.body = body
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "todoList"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "NotificationAt-\(date))", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
  //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Pass start `Date` in dateStart variable and `Date` End Date in dateEnd variable.

Comment: Does start date will be starting hour of day and ending date will be ending hour of day?
meaning if I will pass 7am as starting date and 7pm as ending date then does the notification appear daily between those hours for every half hour?

Comment: @Waqar Khalid Yes, if you set dateStart as 7AM and dateEnd as 7PM then notification will show in every half an hour interval for every day between these time.